# How to stream data from Broadcast Receiver to Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, sqlite

I want to stream data from Broadcast Receiver (native Android) to Flutter.

The Receiver :

```
public class SentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
 @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onReceive: "  + intent.getAction());
        int resultCode = this.getResultCode();
        boolean successfullySent = resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK;

        if (successfullySent)
        {

            String messageId = intent.getStringExtra("messageId");
            Log.e(TAG, "run: " +messageId);
            //From here I want to stream data 
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code in Flutter to receive the data:

```
static const sentSMSChannel = EventChannel(RECEIVE_REPORT);

onStreamSent() {
    _streamSubscription
    =sentSMSChannel.receiveBroadcastStream().listen((event) {
      print(event);
    });
}
```

I need a way to receive the delivery or sent report from native to Flutter or a way to access the Flutter SQLite database from native Android to update the rows.

Database init in Flutter:

```
_database = await _initDB("ESNanoSoft.db");
```

And this code to init the database and open it:

```
Future<Database> _initDB(String filePath) async {
    final dbPath = await getDatabasesPath();
    final path = join(dbPath, filePath);

    return await openDatabase(path,
        version: dbVersion, onCreate: _createDB, onUpgrade: _onUpgrade);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create native [EventChannel](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/EventChannel.html) and `setStreamHandler` to get access to [EventSink](https://api.flutter.dev/javadoc/io/flutter/plugin/common/EventChannel.EventSink.html). Use `EventSink` to send events to Flutter.

See [Add an Android platform-specific implementation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels#step-3-add-an-android-platform-specific-implementation) for details. In this case `EventChannel` replaces `MethodChannel`.